# Записывается только одна строка в txt Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Нужно вывести результат выполнения SQL запроса с базы данных MySQL в файл txt.

Не особо работал с записью в файл, поэтому ничего не понимаю почему записывается только одна строка.
Пробовал как `file.write` так и `file.writelines`

И так...

После выполнения sql запроса `SELECT * FROM accounts` и последующего сразу же `print` показывает все таблицы, в терминале.[image: SQL запрос]
Отлично! Запишем же в файл, верно?
Записывается только последний результат...[image: Попытка записи]

Что делать с этим, не совсем понимаю...

Код:

```
try:
        get_accounts = "SELECT * FROM accounts"
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(get_accounts)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in result:
                print(row)
try:
 file = open("out.txt", "a")
 file.writelines(str(row))
```

Пробовал вот так, не особо менялась ситуация.

````
 with open("out.txt","a") as file:
     file.write('\n'.join(str(row)))```
````

Comment: Вы пытались `file.writelines(result)`?

Comment: И в правду, мне кажется это буквально единственное что я не пробовал, лол.
4 часа времени потрачены впустую...
Спасибо, @re1von!

Comment: И всё же, почему не получается записать `row`?

Comment: `row` отлично записывается, но только на момент записи она равняется последнему значению `result` и вам нужно записывать `row` в файл методом `.write(row)` в цикле `for row in result`.